How should I find the equilibrium points and the general equation for the phase paths?
Find the equilibrium points and the general equation for the phase paths of $\ddot{x}+\cos(x)=0$. Obtain the equation of the phase path joining two adjacent saddles.
Above is the problem statement and the book says "For the general equation $\ddot{x}=f(x,\dot{x})$, equilibrium points lie on the $x$ axis, and are given by all solutions of $f(x, 0)=0$, and the phase paths in the plane $(x, y) (y=\dot{x})$ are given by all solutions of the first-order equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{f(x, y)}{y}$."
Here's my work below:
Consider the differential equation $\ddot{x}+\cos(x)=0$.
Note that $\ddot{x}=f(x, \dot{x})$, so we have $f(x, y)=-\cos(x)$.
Then $f(x, 0)=-\cos(x)=0$.
This gives $x=n\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.
Since the differential equation for the phase paths is given by $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-\cos(x)}{y}$, it follows that $y dy=-\cos(x)dx\implies \int y dy=-\int \cos(x)dx\implies \frac{y^2}{2}=-\sin(x)+C$.
Thus, $y^2=-2\sin(x)+C\implies y=\pm\sqrt{C-2\sin(x)}$ where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.
How should I find the equilibrium points from the work shown above? I've only found the general equation/solution for the phase paths of $\ddot{x}+\cos(x)=0$ but how should I obtain the equation of the phase path joining two adjacent saddles?

Assuming all your work is correct, you have $y_n=\pm \sqrt{-2+2\sin(x)}$ when the initial equilibrium point is one where $n$ is odd and $y_n=\pm \sqrt{2+2\sin(x)}$ when the initial equilibrium point is one where $n$ is even. The plus/minus distinguishes whether the path goes from the $n$th equilibrium to the $(n-1)$th equilibrium or to the $(n+1)$th equilibrium.

For some possible context and Google purposes: The substitution $z=x+\pi/2$ yields the original equation as $\ddot{z}=-\sin z$. That's the equation of motion for a mathematical pendulum. (The phase path of interest amounts to a pendulum swinging from its upright orientation back to itself; such a path requires infinite time, but the phase path is still well-defined.)

@Ian , so what are the equilibrium points in this problem? Is it $(0, \sqrt{-2+2sin(x)}$ and $(0, \sqrt{2+2sin(x)}$? And how to obtain the equation of the phase path joining two adjacent saddles?

They are each $(n\pi-\pi/2,0)$ and I wrote the phase paths, which are just the solutions to the DE you found, subject to starting at one of these equilibria and choosing a departure direction. (Again I am assuming your work above is correct.)

I also made a sign error myself, it should be $\pm \sqrt{2-2\sin(x)}$ when $n$ is odd and $\pm \sqrt{-2-2\sin(x)}$ when $n$ is even.

So how to find the equation of the phase path joining two adjacent saddles from here?

We already did. Pick the starting point to be the $n$th saddle and decide whether you move left or right. Then this square root expression describes the phase path.

We have $$x'' + \cos x = 0$$
We can write that as a system of first order equations
$$\begin{align} x_1' &= x_2 \\ x_2' &= -\cos x_1 \end{align}$$
To find the critical points, we simultaneously solve $x_1' = x_2' = 0$
$$(x_1,x_2) = \left\{\fbox{$2 \pi  c_1-\frac{\pi }{2}\text{ if }c_1\in \mathbb{Z}$},0\right\},\left\{\fbox{$2 \pi  c_1+\frac{\pi }{2}\text{ if }c_1\in \mathbb{Z}$},0\right\}$$
We plot the phase portrait with nullclines (intersections are critical points)

We can plot the contour plot for one of your solutions the way you did it (which seems harder)

Compare that to the diagram above.

Are critical points the same thing as equilibrium points? And how should I find the equation of the phase path joining two adjacent saddles?

Yes - critical points are the same as equilibrium points. I am not sure about your second question.

You normally do not do phase portraits by finding equations, it is more of a qualitative analysis and plotting some directions for slopes - as in https://www.math.unl.edu/~mbrittenham2/classwk/221f09/handouts/linsys.pdf

Okay, got it. Thank you so much for your help. I was confused about the wording in this problem because of equilibrium points (same as critical points) but now the misunderstanding is clear.

The simplest way to display phase paths as contours is to note that this is a Hamiltonian system with Hamiltonian $H(x,\dot{x})=\dot{x}^2/2+\cos x$. Then the contours are the level sets of   $H(x,\dot{x})$, with those of interest here being $H(x,\dot{x})=1$.

@Semiclassical: Great point!

@Moo, may you please take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4968192/how-does-the-classification-of-these-fixed-points-changes-with-epsilon ?
