How does the classification of these fixed points changes with $\epsilon$?
Write the second-order differential equation $\ddot{x}+2\epsilon\dot{x}+sin(x)=0, \epsilon\geq 0$, as a pair of coupled first-order equations. Find all its fixed points, and determine how the classification of these fixed points changes with $\epsilon$.
Here's my work:
Consider the second-order differential equation $\ddot{x}+2\epsilon\dot{x}+sin(x)=0, \epsilon\geq 0$.
Let $\dot{x}=y$ and $\ddot{x}=\dot{y}$.
Then we have $\ddot{x}+2\epsilon\dot{x}+sin(x)=0\implies \ddot{x}=-2\epsilon y-sin(x)\implies \dot{y}=-sin(x)-2\epsilon y$.
Hence, a pair of coupled first-order equations is $\dot{x}=y$ and $\dot{y}=-sin(x)-2\epsilon y$.
By definition, the fixed points occur where $\dot{x}=0$ and $\dot{y}=0$.
Note that $\dot{x}=y=0$ and $\dot{y}=-sin(x)-2\epsilon y=0$.
This gives $\dot{y}=-2\epsilon(0)-sin(x)=0$, so we get $sin(x)=0$.
Thus, $x=\pi n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $y=0$ where the fixed points are $(n\pi, 0)$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.
The Jacobi matrix is $J=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -cos(x) & -2\epsilon \end{bmatrix}$.
Since $cos(n\pi)=(-1)^{n}$ for $x=n\pi$, it follows that $J=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ (-1)^{n+1} & -2\epsilon \end{bmatrix}$ and $det\begin{bmatrix} -\lambda & 1 \\ (-1)^{n+1} & -2\epsilon-\lambda \end{bmatrix}=0$.
Observe that $-\lambda(-2\epsilon-\lambda)-(-1)^{n+1}=0\implies \lambda^2+2\epsilon\lambda+(-1)^{n}=0\implies \lambda=\frac{-2\epsilon\pm\sqrt{4\epsilon^2-4(-1)^{n}}}{2}$.
Thus, the eigenvalues are $\lambda=-\epsilon\pm\sqrt{\epsilon^2+(-1)^{n+1}}$.
Now we will consider two cases of $n$.
Case #1: Let $n$ be an odd integer such that $x=n\pi$.
Then $x=\pi, 3\pi, 5\pi,...$ .
Note that $(-1)^{n+1}=1$ for any odd integer $n$.
Hence, the eigenvalues are $\lambda=-\epsilon\pm\sqrt{\epsilon^2+1}$.
Thus, the fixed points $(n\pi, 0)$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ are saddle points for all $\epsilon$ and unstable.
Case #2: Let $n$ be an even integer such that $x=n\pi$.
Then $x=2\pi, 4\pi, 6\pi,...$ .
Note that $(-1)^{n+1}=-1$ for any even integer $n$.
Hence, the eigenvalues $\lambda=-\epsilon\pm\sqrt{\epsilon^2-1}$ are real for $\epsilon>1$.
Thus, the fixed points $(n\pi, 0)$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ are stable for $\epsilon>1$.
Therefore, a pair of coupled first-order equations for the second-order differential equation $\ddot{x}+2\epsilon\dot{x}+sin(x)=0, \epsilon\geq 0$ is $\dot{x}=y$ and $\dot{y}=-sin(x)-2\epsilon y$. The fixed points are $(n\pi, 0)$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and the classification of these fixed points changes with $\epsilon$ such that the fixed points $(n\pi, 0)$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ are unstable saddle points for all $\epsilon$ where $n$ is any odd integer and the fixed points $(n\pi, 0)$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ are stable nodes for $\epsilon>1$ where $n$ is any even integer.
Above is my work with answer for this problem. May anyone please check/verify/confirm to see if it's 100% correct?

Write the second order DEQ as a system of first order equations
$$\begin{align} x ' &= y \\ y' &= -\sin x -2 \epsilon y \end{align}$$
We find fixed points by solving $x' = y' = 0$
$$(x, y) = ~~(k~ \pi , 0),~~ k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
The Jacobian is given by
$$J(x, y) = \begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial x'}{\partial x}& \dfrac{\partial x'}{\partial y}\\
\dfrac{\partial y'}{\partial x}& \dfrac{\partial y'}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-\cos x & -\epsilon
\end{bmatrix}$$
Now, we evaluate the eigenvalues of the Jacobian at each critical point. It turns out that the eigenvalues are also dependent on $\epsilon$.
Now, analyze the eigenvalues for some critical points and different $\epsilon$
$$(x, y) = (-\pi,0),(0,0),(\pi,0)$$
For example, the eigenvalues will go from a neutral center to unstable saddle for $\epsilon = 0$ and a stable node to a saddle for $\epsilon = 1$ as can be seen in the following phase portraits.



How are the two fixed points $(x, y)=(2\pi c, 0), (\pi+2\pi c, 0)$ for some $c\in\mathbb{Z}$? I get that $y=0$ but how did you get $2\pi c, \pi+2\pi c$? Also, why is $\frac{\partial y'}{\partial x}=cos(x)$ instead of $\frac{\partial y'}{\partial x}=-cos(x)$?

If you plot $\sin x = 0$, you see that the values of $x$ are periodic and can be written as $$x = k~\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$ This is probably a simpler way to write the critical points as opposed to the way I wrote it (same result in the end) as this gives $$x =\ldots -4 \pi ,-3 \pi ,-2 \pi ,-\pi ,0,\pi ,2 \pi ,3 \pi ,4 \pi ,5 \pi ,6 \pi \ldots, y = 0$$ Answer updated with this cleanup, which makes everything easier to understand.

I mean, I really don't mind if it's $x=k\pi, k\in\mathbb{Z}$ or $(x, y)=(2\pi c, 0), (\pi+2\pi c, 0)$ for some $c\in\mathbb{Z}$ as long as they are the same.

It is a periodic critical point based on $x$, so you can just write it all critical points as $$(x, y) = (k \pi, 0)$$ That covers all the values as there are infinite critical points because it is periodic.

After finding the determinant, I've got $\lambda^2+\epsilon\lambda+cos(x)=0$ and so the eigenvalues are $\frac{-\epsilon\pm\sqrt{\epsilon^2-4cos(x)}}{2}$. Is this correct?

That is correct, but normally, you first substitute in the critical point of interest and then find the eigenvalues for that specific point.

So I've got $\frac{-\epsilon\pm\sqrt{\epsilon^2-4cos(k\pi)}}{2}$ where $x=k\pi$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. But how to determine that the classification of these fixed points changes with $\epsilon$? In fact, what's $\epsilon$, really? Is it just a very small positive number?

According to your problem write up, $\epsilon \ge 0$, with no other restrictions on size. So, I assume any real that is greater than or equal to zero. You have to pick an epsilon and a critical point and analyze the result and then pick another $x$ and repeat for several epsilons., etc. it is easiest if you can simulate the system for like my phase portraits show - a single epsilon and a bunch of critical points.

How come I didn't notice that $\epsilon\geq 0$ in the first place? Thank you so much for your hint(s) and answer!

May you please take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4969416/how-should-i-describe-the-qualitative-features-of-the-motion-of-a-particle-of-un ?
