How should I describe the qualitative features of the motion of a particle of unit mass moving in the following potentials?
Describe the qualitative features of the motion of a particle of unit mass moving in the following potentials. In each case, sketch the potential and the phase diagram, and give equations of any separatrices that exist.
a) $V(x)=x^2(x^2-1)^2$
b) $V(x)=x(x^2-1)^2$
Here's my work:
a) Consider the potential $V(x)=x^2(x^2-1)^2$.
Then $V(x)=x^2(x^2-1)^2=0\implies x=0, \pm 1$.
Note that $V(-x)=-V(x)$ where $V(x)=x^2(x^2-1)(x^2-1)=x^6-2x^4+x^2$.
This gives $\frac{dV}{dx}=6x^5-8x^3+2x=0$ for $x=-1, -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}, 0, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}, 1$.
Above is my partial work for this problem. I've used WA for the sketch of the potential for part a) on https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=V%28x%29%3Dx%5E2%28x%5E2-1%29%5E2 but how should I describe the qualitative features of the motion of a particle of unit mass moving in these potentials? And how to sketch the phase diagram, also give equations of any separatrices that exist?

Note: You should be able to produce a qualitative sketch of the potential function just by looking at the roots and their multiplicities.

btw, $V(-x)$ is not $-V(x)$, the function in part (a) is clearly an even function (it depends only on $x^2$), so $V(-x)=V(x)$. I’m not sure if you ever used this anywhere (hopefully not). With this evenness observation, you should get another nice qualitative feature of the graph.

What's the basic relationship between the motion of a particle and its potential function? You likely know relevant things that you have not included in your post.

@Sammy Black, that I don't know. Is it related to an equation or something in order to describe that relationship?

Let's back up then. Where did you encounter these notions? Why are you asking us, the community of Math.SE about this? What have you learned that's relevant?

From an outer source and it's not included in my textbook.

Okay, so you likely know that net change in potential energy is related to the work put into a body in the presence of a force: $\Delta V = -W = - \int F , \mathrm{d}x$ so the derivative of the potential function predicts the net force. In the presence of a constant mass $m$, this predicts the acceleration:
$$
a = \frac1m F = -\frac1m \frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}x}.
$$

How to find $m$ from here?

It has no effect on the qualitative description of motion, as it is a constant and only scales the relevant functions. Also, you claim in your title that $m = 1$. I'm just including it for completeness.

The method consists of drawing the potential. fix the constant energy level given by the kinetic energy in the minimum of V. Draw the line of constant enery and look for its point crossing the potential graph. These are points of return. In a) you find two stable minima for low energy and symmetric oscillations for high energy. In the second case only one stable minimum and runaway solutions fo higher energies.

Phase portraits correspond to the curves associated to a dynamical system in its phase space. In the present case, the said dynamical system is simply given by Hamilton's equations, i.e $\dot{x} = \frac{p}{m}$ and $\dot{p} = -V'(x)$. By trying to deduce $p(x)$ from $\frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{\dot{p}}{\dot{x}}$ and integration by separation of variables, you will end up with phase diagrams corresponding to the curves of constant energy, whose points $(x,p)$ satisfy $\frac{p^2}{2m} + V(x) = E = const$. Let's study the qualitative features of the said curves with respect to the two given potentials.

1st potential : $V(x) = x^2(x-1)^2(x+1)^2$
You have derived the main properties of $V(x)$ already (see here). Basically, it is a sextic polynomial with a (degenerate) minimal value $V_0 = 0$ at $x = -1,0,1$ and two local maxima at $x = \frac{\pm1}{\sqrt{3}}$, with $V_{max} = \frac{4}{27}$.
Since $V(\pm\infty) = +\infty$, one can deduce that all curves of the phase diagram will be closed orbits, because the particle cannot have enough energy to "escape" this potential. In consequence, $x(t)$ and $p(t)$ will be oscillatory functions $-$ they are not harmonic oscillators, but the more circular their orbits in phase space, the more harmonically they behave.
Now, when $V_0 \le E < V_{max}$, the particle doesn't possess enough energy to go from one local potential well to another, in such a way that the a particle starting from the neighbourhood of a minimum point won't be able to bypass the potential barrier around this point and thus will trapped in the said local well. In consequence, the aforementioned closed orbits will be disjoint.
On the contrary, when $E > V_{max}$, there is one single orbit, because the particle is not stopped by the barriers represented by the local maxima at $x = \frac{\pm1}{\sqrt{3}}$. Finally, the separatrix corresponds to the case $E = V_{max}$.
You can visualize these orbits here for instance.

2nd potential : $V(x) = x(x-1)^2(x+1)^2$
This potential possesses two local minima at $x = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ and $x = 1$, as well as two local maxima at $x = -1$ and $x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ (see here), while $x = 0$ is just a saddle point. You can apply basically the same reasoning as before with local wells and disjoint orbits depending on the considered energy intervals.
However, there is one important difference here. Since $V$ is unbounded from below, meaning that it doesn't show a global minimum, because $V(x) \to -\infty$ when $x \to -\infty$, it implies that the curves of the phase diagram are not closed orbits and that the particle is confined to the left region (with respect to $x$), because of the infinite potential barrier on the right. As before, the separatrices corresponds to values of energy which are equal to the maxima of the potential (see here).

Thank you so much!

May you please take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4974233/how-should-i-show-that-the-index-of-a-limit-cycle-is-1 ? I need help on this problem.
